# Переменная через глобал не полностью передается

Tags: php

Привет всем! Столкнулся с приколом, у меня 3 файла

- config.php (содержит настройки)
- index.php (главная)
- functions.php

**config.php** содержит

```
$level['admin'] = "red";
$level['user'] = "orange";
$level['all'] = "black";
```

**functions.php**

```
function level($name, $id){
    global $level;
    if($id == 1)
        return "<font color=".$level['user'].">".$name."</font>";
    elseif($id == 2)
        return "<font color='".$level['admin']."'>".$name."</font>";
    else
        return "<font color='".$level['all']."'>".$name."</font>";
}
```

**Index.php**

```
print level($name, $id);
```

Ошибок не каких нет. Но массив $level[] - передает только первую букву. Если красный, то "r", если черный, то "b". Пример исходного кода в браузере

```
<font color="b">Node</font>
```

Comment: Не удается воспроизвести ошибку, всё отрабатывает на ура. Скорей всего, разная кодировка у файлов (index, config, functions).

Comment: Если бы была разная кодировка — оно бы вообще не работало — не было бы никаких `$level`, не говоря уже о `$level['user']`.

Думаю, можно влепить для теста `return var_export($level, true);` (или как оно там, в PHP) и посмотреть, что, собственно, там такое творится.

Comment: print_r() оно в пхп или var_dump()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте ваш $name, перед вызовом функции:

```
var_damp($name);
```

внтури функции, после 
global $level;

```
var_dump($level);
```

и всё скрытой станет явным.

Ставлю на то, что в $name фигня ..

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить названия цветов 16-тиричным эквивалентом

```
red = #F00
orange = #FFA500
black = #000
```

Comment: только #

Comment: После include "config.php" попробуйте вписать echo $level['admin'];
Возможно переменная уже где-то использовалась.

Comment: Лучше `var_dump`, сразу всю структуру целиком покажет.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, но в одном файле все работает. Вы в index.php все файлы правильно подключаете?

Comment: да, переменные работает, просто одну букву берет.